# Deletion threshold for inconclusive answers

Tags: discussion

there is some disagreement between me and several people over this answer:
https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/44989/50610

Others say that I did not provide enough evidence to meet the standards of this site.

I disagree, and although I am not fully satisfied either I think I was able to add something to the discussion. There are plenty of answers here that end with an "inconclusive, not enough evidence"

So: what is the line between "inconclusive, lets not write this answer" and "inconclusive, and thats my answer" ?

Answer (score -1):

There are two issues here.

The first is that the answer should provide higher-quality evidence than the source of the claim. This was discussed here: [May I cite a single article?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2526/may-i-cite-a-single-article/2528#2528)

You answer repeated the claim at the same level of trust as the original source - i.e. bartender lore - which makes it inadequate as an answer.

The second is that you argue that no-one knows why wetting the glass works. That needs a reference. Yes, it is hard to prove that the lack of evidence is because the field doesn't know it (versus the answerer did poor research), so we accept a slightly lower hurdle here. This has been discussed frequently. Here are a couple of examples:

- [What makes a good "the answer is unknown" answer?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3927/what-makes-a-good-the-answer-is-unknown-answer/3932#3932)
- [Should "absence of evidence" questions be allowed?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1210/should-absence-of-evidence-questions-be-allowed/1409#1409)

Comment: ok, this is exactly the kind of reference I needed. I suggest you link to those meta-questions if you want a answer deleted in the future. I'll remove mine although I still think it is a valid answer.